# iOSアプリのリリース作業にて、XcodeでArchive後にValidateボタンが押せない

Tags: ios, xcode

iOSアプリリリースにあたって、[このリンク](http://qiita.com/knife0125/items/05ef8bd6a5dc5fd9cd44)を参考にArchiveファイルの作成を行っています。

Archive後にOrganizerウィンドウが立ち上がったのですが、Validateボタンがグレーアウトされていて、押すことができません。（下記画像の赤文字1を参照）
またDetailsについてもidentifer等が空になっています。（下記画像の赤文字2を参照）

Exportはできるのですが、審査のリジェクトをさけるため必要な手順は踏みたいと思っています。Validateが押せない、Detailsが空の原因として考えられるのはどういったものでしょうか？

[image: Archive後のウィンドウ]

環境: 
Xcode7.2
CocoaPods 0.38.2

Comment: Generic Xcode Archiveとなっているので、正しくアーカイブが作成されていません。具体的にはiOSアプリケーションやエクステンションのディレクトリ構成が間違っているなどの問題があります。たいていは、あなたの問題ではなく、CocoaPodsなどによって起こることが多いです。実際に作成されたアーカイブのディレクトリ構造や使っている環境（Xcodeや、使っていればCocoaPodsなどのバージョン）を差し支えない範囲で書いてください。アーカイブの問題はリモートで解決するにはかなり複雑なので、もし可能ならプロジェクトを共有するか送っていただけると、より適切にアドバイスできると思います。

Comment: まさに仰る通りCocoaPodsのバージョンによる問題でした。編集にてCocoaPodsのバージョンを追加しました。多少時間は使いましたが無事解決しましたので、後ほど自分なりに調査した結果をもとに回答を追加させていただきます。親身にコメントいただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回のケースは以下の2点を確認することで解決しました。

- [このリンク](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2215/_index.html)を参考にサブプロジェクトのBuild Settingを見直す
- [このリンク](http://qiita.com/Branch_Dev/items/4fd1abb9c2891752e47b)を参考にCocoaPodsを最新のものにアップデートし、Podsデータを作り直す

Generic Xcode Archiveで調べるとCocoaPods 0.38.2利用時に、Archiveの不具合が複数報告されていました。
通常、Archiveがうまくいけば、iOS App Archiveタイプのバイナリが1つ生成されますが、プロジェクトまたはサブプロジェクトのビルド設定、CocoaPodsのバージョン、ディレクトリ構造の誤りによって、バイナリが複数生成されてしまう条件下では質問画像のような結果になります。

Answer (score 0):

参考にされている記事がやや古い気がしますが、手順通りにやれば概ね問題ないはずだと思います。

下記を確認してはいかがでしょうか？
・`iTunes Connect`のアプリの申請枠が存在することを確認する
・`MemberCenter`の`Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`より
　　・`App IDs`に対象のアプリがあることを確認する
　　・Distribution用のProfileが存在することを確認する
・改めてビルド設定を確認する

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。仰っていただいた項目を順につぶしていったところ、ビルド設定にいくつかの問題と、CocoaPodsによる問題を発見しました。大変参考になりました。改めて回答に調査した結果や参考になったリンクを追加させていただきます。